# How to select records in one table based on a common id value from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return the "description" field in table ca_list_item_labels, based on a common field (item_id) between ca_list_item_labels and ca_list_items, where list_id = 41 in ca_list_items.

The closest thing I can manage is with a subquery...I am fairly new to writing mySQL queries.

I've tried the following two queries without any success:

```
    SELECT description FROM ca_list_item_labels UNION SELECT * FROM ca_list_items WHERE 'list_id' = 41;

    SELECT description FROM ca_list_item_labels WHERE (SELECT item_id FROM ca_list_items WHERE 'list_id' = 41);
```

Comment: I think that you could try with JOINS, however, it would be nice that you post db scheme here, with few test entries and desired output. Or, even better - setup sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with a simple join.  Something like this should work:

```
   SELECT decsription 
   FROM ca_list_item_labels JOIN ca_list_items USING (item_id) 
   WHERE list_id = 41
```

Comment: It's impossible to say why that is without knowing a little more about the tables.  As suggested above, an sqlfiddle example or just posting the schema would help.

Comment: Sorry about that, issue was between keyboard and chair. Got her purring, and excluding the couple records I didn't want in there. Thanks for the kick in the right direction. Joins are cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JOIN-query`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.description FROM ca_list_items AS a
                          LEFT JOIN ca_list_item_labels AS b 
                          ON a.list_id = b.list_id
                          WHERE a.list_id = 41
```

Assuming here, that list_id is the same on both tables.